# iOS give notification a title using node-apn

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, node-apn

Is there a way to set a bolded notification title (like most apps have) using node-apn? I've tried the following setters:

```
notification.body = "Body";
notification.title = "Title";
notification.alert = "Alert";
```

but only the alert is included in the notification and it's in regular text, appearing kind of odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the title in the alert object like this

```
alert: {
    title: 'heres the title',
    body: 'heres a body'
}
```